# Print columnnames as vector

Tags: r, vector, tibble, r-colnames

My code prints a tibble as binary matrix. It prints a binary matrix if a specific stringpart is matched (with grepl).

This is my output.

```
 A tibble: 11 × 6
   Aufzeichnungen                                                                             `2010` `0070` Ä1    Ä5    `0010`
   <chr>                                                                                      <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
 1 Aufzeichnungen                                                                             0      0      0     0     0     
 2 07.03.22   A: stechender Schmerz,    scharfkantig                                          0      0      0     0     0     
 3 D/B:                                                                                       0      0      0     0     0     
 4 T:                                                                                         0      0      0     0     0     
 5 pat aht an 36 üz distal, seit paartagen                                                    1      0      0     1     0     
 6 36 vipr++, perk-, keine c zu entdekcne,üz bilfuird                                         1      1      0     0     0     
 7 pat aufgekläörtggf  RÖ um c auszuschileßen, pat verweigert RÖ aus Angst vor Strahlung, pat 0      0      0     0     0     
 8 aufgeklärt angst nicht nötig und c unter fllg oder apprx nicht auszuschließen,             0      0      1     0     0     
 9 pat knirscht, schiene empohlen, pat meldet sich..                                          0      0      0     0     0     
10 next: noch schmerezn                                                                       0      0      0     0     0     
11 an 36?                                                                                     0      0      0     0     0     
>
```

and from this point I want to generate as output a vector which gives me the column-names where column-sum > 0.

Like for this example (2010, 0070, Ä1, Ä5)

I tried it with a own function and colSums but here is the first column a problem, because its a character.
I tought about to remove the first column for the process and add it for the context later, but maybe there is a simpler way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the numeric columns before checking the column sum:

```r
tibble(a = c("a", "b", "c"), b = c(0,0,0), c = c(0,0,1)) |>
  select(where(is.numeric)) |> 
  select(where(~ sum(.) > 0)) |>
  names()
```

Output:

```r
[1] "c"
```